# How to fix the errors with node version up

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have serious error occuring by version up.
I made a program in 18.x few years ago.
Now I version up node.js
And I have some errors.
Here are error messages:

```
ERROR in ./app/assets/scss/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./app/assets/scss/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (120)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at getDefaultSassImpl (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:198:10)
    at Object.loader (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:80:29)
ERROR in ./app/containers/UserDashboard/assets/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./app/containers/UserDashboard/assets/style.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (120)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at getDefaultSassImpl (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:198:10)
    at Object.loader (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:80:29)
ERROR in ./app/assets/scss/components/register.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./app/assets/scss/components/register.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (120)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at getDefaultSassImpl (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:198:10)
    at Object.loader (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:80:29)
ERROR in ./app/components/CustomTable/components/pagination.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./app/components/CustomTable/components/pagination.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (120)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at getDefaultSassImpl (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:198:10)
    at Object.loader (F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Blockchain\wallet_frontend_react\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:80:29)
```

Until now I haven't error because of version up so I don't know what I have to do.
How can I fix this problem?

I want build the project with out errors

Comment: Have you also updated the versions of dependencies? E.g., node-sass is on version 9. Particularly for things like node-sass versions matter.

Comment: I don't know how to virsion up node-sass module.

Comment: … change the version in package.json?

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, this error is related `node sass` version.
so to solve this problem you can use following command.

```
 npm install node-sass@latest
```

or

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
npm cache clean --force 
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```